# run docker-compose in case of change

Tags: docker-compose

I would like to run the following docker-compose operations only in case there is any change in docker-compose.yml file:

1. docker-compose pull
2. docker-compose down
3. docker-compose up -d

Is there any way if we can achieve this? I am not quite sure if we can really do that.

Thanks in advance,
Sanjiv

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you need this, but your question is not how to run commands but detect file change that is similar to this post:

- https://superuser.com/a/181543

Only you will run your script instead of .py with those commands.

But If you have unchanged docker images you colud always call ***docker-compose pull*** and ***docker-compose up -d your_service_name*** whitout any effect on running containers. If there would be change they will be automaticly be pulled and recreated. Or call this after your *"release"* if I can call it that way and make some automation to it.

Comment: thanks JozeFe. Your answer gave me a pointer to proceed with in-house solution.